# Identity Server and custom user class

Tags: asp.net-web-api, identityserver4, blazor-webassembly

I am using **Identity Server 4** with a **Blazor WASM** App and a WebApi

Serverside I use `HttpContextAccessor` to retrieve information about the logged in user.

```
HttpContext.User.Identity returns a ClaimsIdentity.
```

Shouldn't that somehow return an instance of my own user class which inherits from `IIdentity`?

Or are those different systems, my custom user class is irrelevant and the only thing that matters are the claims from `HttpContext.User.Identity.Claims`?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If the user authenticates using OpenID-connect and IdentityServer, in that case, the ClaimsIdentity is created based only on what is found inside the ID-token (and optionally from the data retrieved from the UserInfo endpoint).

ASP.NET Identity is not involved here.